# How to refresh a div of a page to load the updated value from the database?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I am having a `viewcount` feature in my post of a small blog project which counts the number of times a particular blog has been viewed, but after viewing a particular blog, the value of the `viewcount` remains unchanged until the entire page is refreshed. So, I am trying to figure out a way to refresh only that portion of the `div` section which is containing the `viewcount` value.
Here is my required portion of the html code:-

```
{% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}" onclick="ViewCountRefresh()">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <div class="article-metadata" id="viewcountrefresh">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'blog-profile' name=post.author %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <img style="height:19px; width:18px; float:right;" src="{% static "blog/viewicon.png" %}"><p id="viewcountrefresh" style="float: right; display: inline !important;">{{post.view_count}}</p></img>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|truncatechars:200|safe }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my `views.py` file:-

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj.view_count += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Here's the urls.py file:-

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
        PostDetailView,
        home,
    )

urlpatterns = [
    path("", home, name="blog-home"),
    path("post/<slug:slug>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
]
```

I am trying to refresh the content of the div section containing the id `viewcountrefresh` so that when any blog is visited, and then I come back to my homepage I get the updated value of the `viewcount` from the database.
Here is the js script:-

```
function ViewCountRefresh(){
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

I am a beginner in javascript & ajax, so having a hard time figuring out the code that would solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update data on a page without refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577457/update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this assuming you want to update the counts whenever you click on that heading. [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
function ViewCountRefresh(){
    //assuming you are using es6 and you are not supporting IE11
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(countViews) {
                var viewcountrefreshDiv = document.querySelector('#viewcountrefresh');
                var paragraphTag = viewcountrefreshDiv.querySelector('p');
                paragraphTag.innerText = countViews;
        });
}
```

Comment: Hey @lucio-poveda, I am trying to follow what you have mentioned here, but still the problem exists. I have updated the questions with all the required codes, Can you please help me I am stuck with this error.