# How to soft reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, performance

I have one page with dynamic data which is constantly being updated in the database, i am finding a way to softly reload page i tried location.reload but it refreshes page hardly. I want to refresh only data in that divs not entire page

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. But the best approach is going to be to make a [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) request to re-fetch the data, and then update the DOM accordingly. But your question doesn't contain enough info to provide an adequate answer.

Comment: [Jean-Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2431885/jean-paul) has already answered this question in --> [Update data on a page without refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577457/update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing)

Comment: Those very old answers on the linked page don't know about Livewire. This would do what you want very easily.